# Prove $\lim\limits_{x^2 + y^2 \to +\infty} x^2 -2xy + 2y^2 = +\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

> Prove that $$\lim_{x^2 + y^2 \to +\infty} x^2 -2xy + 2y^2 = +\infty$$

---

My attempt:

$$x^2 + 2y^2 = x^2+y^2 + y^2  \implies \lim_{x^2 + y^2 \to +\infty}x^2 +2y^2 = +\infty$$

Then, from Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$x^2 + 2y^2 \geq 2\sqrt2xy \geq 2xy $$

Thus,

$$x^2+2y^2 -2xy \geq 0$$

I think I am on the correct path, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: If you don't want to use polar coordinates, write it as $(x-y)^2+y^2$ and observe this quantity will become arbitrarily large as a function of $y$ alone.

Comment: Also, in polar coordinates: $\rho^2[(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)^2+\sin^2\theta],$ and the bracket is strictly positive, while $\rho\to+\infty$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that

$$x^2 -2xy + 2y^2 =(x-y)^2+y^2\ge y^2$$

$$x^2 -2xy + 2y^2 =\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt 2}-\sqrt 2y\right)^2+\frac{x^2}2\ge \frac{x^2}2 $$

therefore

$$x^2 -2xy + 2y^2 \ge \frac{x^2+2y^2}4 \ge \frac{x^2+y^2}4\to \infty$$

Answer (score 2):

Because $$x^2-2xy+2y^2\geq\frac{1}{3}(x^2+y^2)\rightarrow+\infty.$$
$$x^2-2xy+2y^2\geq\frac{1}{3}(x^2+y^2)$$ it's
$$3x^2-6xy+6y^2\geq x^2+y^2$$ or
$$2x^2-6xy+5y^2\geq0,$$ which is true because $$3^2-2\cdot5<0.$$

Comment: How did you make the 1st step? It is not obvious. Whereas the 2nd step is.

Answer (score 2):

Note: If $xy<0$, then $2\sqrt{2}xy \leq 2xy$. So the Cauchy-Schwartz argument may not hold.

However, $x^2-2xy+y^2 =(x-y)^2 \geq 0$. So as $x^2+y^2\rightarrow\infty$, $x^2-2xy+y^2+y^2\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: I am sorry, but I dont understand the last part.Obviously we have a sum of two squares which is alway positives, but why does the left side $\rightarrow\infty$ ?

Comment: We only have to show that $x^2-2xy+y^2\rightarrow\infty$ since something that approaches infinity plus a positive number approaches infinity. Now, we can use polar coordinates with $x=r\cos(a), y=r\sin(a)$. We will get $$x^2-2xy+y^2 = r^2-r^2\sin(2a) = r^2(1-\sin(2a))\rightarrow\infty$$ as $r^2\rightarrow\infty$ because $\sin(2a)\leq 1$

Comment: @morphy22 The problem with this proof  is that for $x=y$ the expression $(x-y)^2$ is equal to zero.

Comment: Yes. But if that is the case, $x^2-2xy+2y^2=x^2$ and you will get the limit as $2x^2\rightarrow\infty$ which still goes to $+\infty$.

Comment: @morphy22 Yes of course but we need to make a rigorous proof of that intuition. You have shown that $x^2-2xy+y^2+y^2 \ge y^2$ but this doesn't suffice to conclude.